# Distinct on a specific field

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a class structure:

```
class MyEx{
public int Prop1;
public int Prop2;
public int Prop3
}
```

Prop1 and Prop 2 are always the same , Prop3 varies.
this class I want to retrieve from a longer the end should be something like

```
select new MyEx { Prop1=something;
                  Prop2= something2;
                  Prop3=something3;
}
```

the problem is that something3 is not unique , so I would like to apply a Distinct to thw query in order to obtain the class above with distinct Prop3 values.
But this does not seem to work.
Any ideas why?
Thanks

Comment: "This does not seem to work" - *what* doesn't seem to work? You haven't said what you've tried or what the result is.

Comment: Also, a lot of your question isn't clear, for example "I want to retrieve from a longer the end should be something like" doesn't make any sense. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want [`DistinctBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
var query = items.DistinctBy(x => x.Prop3);
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit like so?

```
public static class SomeHelperClass
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,TValue> selector)
    {
        var hashset = new HashSet<TValue>();
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var value = selector(item);
            if (hashset.Add(value)) yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

then:

```
var distinct = list.DistinctBy(item => item.Prop3);
```