# How to write this complex LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm writing an application that will allow our users to send newsletters to their contacts. Here is the database structure (only important fields):

```
Contacts(tbl)       ContactEmails(tbl)       Newsletters(tbl)
  ContactID           ContactEmailID           NewsletterID
  ...                 ContactID (fk)           ...
                      EmailAddress             
                      Deleted
                      ...


NewsletterLists(tbl)       NewsletterToLists(tbl)
  NewsletterListID           NewsletterID (fk)
  ...                        NewsletterListID (fk)


NewsletterListToContacts(tbl)
  NewsletterListID (fk)
  ContactID (fk)
  Active
  Deleted
  UnsubscribedOn
  ...
```

Now I have a class structured as:

```
public class NewsletterContactEmails
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public List<string> EmailList { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a NewsletterContactEmails object for each contact so that I can loop through it and send one email each contact (not each email address).

I have the Newsletter object to start working with. So in pseudo it would be...

```
1. Get NewsletterLists this newsletter is to send to.
2. Get Active (double opted-in) and non-deleted/unsubscribed DISTINCT Contact List from said NewsletterLists.
3. Create NewsletterContactEmails object for each contact and add their non-deleted DISTINCT list of email addresses.
```

I want to do this in one query. Here is what I currently have, I think I'm close but this won't even compile:

```
List<NewsletterContactEmails> Recipients = objNewsletter.NewsletterToLists
                    .Select(ntl => ntl.NewsletterList.NewsletterListToContacts
                        .Where(nl => nl.Active == true && nl.Deleted == false && nl.UnsubscribedOn == null)
                        .Select(nl => new NewsletterContactEmails {
                            ContactID = nl.ContactID,
                            EmailList = nl.Contact.ContactEmails.Where(ce => ce.Deleted == false).Select(ce => ce.EmailAddress).Distinct().ToList()
                        }));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<NewsletterContactEmails> Recipients = objNewsletter.NewsletterToLists
    .SelectMany(ntl => ntl.NewsletterList.NewsletterListToContacts
        .Where(nl => nl.Active == true && nl.Deleted == false && nl.UnsubscribedOn == null)
        .Select(nl => new NewsletterContactEmails
        {
            ContactID = nl.ContactID,
            EmailList =
                nl.Contact.ContactEmails.Where(ce => ce.Deleted == false)
                    .Select(ce => ce.EmailAddress)
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList()
        }));
```

Try the first select as `SelectMany` instead of `Select`

Comment: That got er done! Also had to add .ToList() at the end of SelectMany. Thanks!!

Comment: Forgot...this won't make the List<NewsletterContactEmails> distinct. There could be the same ContactID twice if they were in more than one list the newsletter was being sent to...how would I add that part?

Comment: Nevermind last comment...found the answer from Skeet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941504/distinct-on-a-specific-field